# Tile in the center coordinates TiledMap

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

**cocos2d**: Can you please tell how to find the coordinates of the middle of the tile on the screen? Ie not the coordinates of the tile (1, 1 or 1, 8) and the coordinates of its center straight
If anything, the coordinates of the tile so I figure

```
- (CGPoint) tileCoordForPosition: (CGPoint) position {
     int x = position.x / _tileMap.tileSize.width;
     int y = ((_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - position.y) / _tileMap.tileSize.height;
     return ccp (x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each CCTMXTiledMap  has a CCTMXLayer which in turn you can use a method tileAt http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_t_m_x_layer.html#a91a1765d9698222d8401b523f9064168 where you pass it coordinates tile coordinates (1, 8) for example and it returns the CCSprite.

With that CCSprite you can then get its position as you would any other CCNode derived object. If you have any funky layering stuff going on you may need to use

```
[thatSprite convertToWorldSpace: thatSprite.position]
```

Comment: I have a sprite and I can drag it. And I need to when I let it raised it in tile